# Convert parameter to string not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am converting test function parameter to string but it is not working.

//script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(a,b,c){
alert(a.toString());
alert(b.toString());
alert(c.toString());
}
</script>
```

// html

```
<input type="text" onblur="test(jitender,chand,thakur)" />
```

Comment: Getting any outputs from the console as to what might be the error?

Comment: limelights: jitender is not define is coming on consloe

Comment: Do you mean this `test('jitender','chand','thakur')`?

Comment: actually value are coming dynamically and we cant add quotes around it.

Comment: Why can't you add quotes? How on earth are you building it if you can't add quotes in them?

Comment: Juhana: My question is to get value from test function's parameter without adding quotes in them

Comment: @amit And the answer is: You can't. You have to add the quotes. Perhaps your question should be "how can I add quotes to these parameters"?

Answer (score 2):

The only way that what you do would be possible, is if you define variables for all names that you will use.

For the names in your example:

```
var jitender = "jitender", chand = "chand", thakur = "thakur";
```

Now your call will work, as the code will use the variables and send the values of the variables to the function.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`test('jitender', 'chand', 'thakur')`

Comment: actually value are coming dynamically and we cant add quotes around it.

Comment: and where are jitender, chand nad thakur defined and whats its content.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the names in single quotes, your name will already be string, you don't need to convert it then.

```
<input type="text" onblur="test('jitender','chand','thakur')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test(a,b,c)
{
   alert(a);
   alert(b);
   alert(c);
}
</script>
```

// html

```
<input type="text" onblur="test('jitender','chand','thakur')" />
```

You need not convert it into string.